# Can you get the mouse position and if it is clicked in a console app?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I want to get the position of the mouse and if it clicks while over a certain part of the screen I want something to happen. Is it possible to do this in a console application or can you only get mouse clicks in a Win32 application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the mouse position in a console program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285270/how-can-i-get-the-mouse-position-in-a-console-program)

Comment: I saw that but it is quite confusing for me and I don't understand it at all

Comment: That post answers the question you asked. It's not up to us to make sure you can understand it - it's the solution. There are both links to the documentation (in the first answer) and an example using code (in the second answer) that should help.

Comment: I know this isn't a answer to your question, but I think you'd better if you learn SDL2, which is far more complete than a Window's console, and is cross-platform. You should look at this tutorial: https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php. PS: I'm not dimishing what you intented to do, I just think you would spend better your time learning SDL2.

Comment: @KenWhite the example doesn't even work